# Why can't the selected files be posted to server client when I use Modal form of jQuery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

The following code  is based jQuery Modal form just like https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form .

I hope to click a button to open a modal form, and select files in the modal form, then click "Upload" button to post data the server side.

But I find the data don't be posted when I click "Upload" button. Why ?

And more, what action is  the code  f`orm = dialog.find("form").on("submit", function (event) {...} ?`  I think I can remove the code `form = dialog.find("form").on("submit", function (event) {...}`, right?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Modal form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
      $(function () {
          var dialog, form;


          function mySubmit() {
              var valid = true;
              if (valid) {
                  dialog.dialog("close");
                  $("#MyUploadFile").submit();               

              }
              return valid;
          }

          dialog = $("#dialog-form").dialog({
              autoOpen: false,
              height: 400,
              width: 350,
              modal: true,
              buttons: {
                  "Upload": mySubmit,
                  Cancel: function () {
                      dialog.dialog("close");
                  }
              },
              close: function () {
                  form[0].reset();
              }
          });

          form = dialog.find("form").on("submit", function (event) {
              event.preventDefault();
              mySubmit();
          });

          $("#create-user").button().on("click", function () {
              dialog.dialog("open");
          });
      });
  </script>
</head>
<body>


<div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
  <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>

     <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="MyUploadFile">               
          <input type="file" name="myupload" multiple="multiple" />           
     </form>                                       

</div>



<button id="create-user">select files and upload</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `But I find the data don't be posted when I click "Upload" button. Why ?` - check your developer tools console/network tabs to see if there's any errors - to me, it looks suspicious that you close the modal before sending the file ...

Comment: also i doubt if you have any other boolean value for var valid. that is always true.

Comment: The data aren't posted cause you cancel "submit" event by `event.preventDefault()` call. Remove `$("#MyUploadFile").submit()` from `mySubmit` and call `preventDefault` depending on `mySubmit` returning value.

Comment: Thanks! but the modified code   form = dialog.find("form").on("submit", function (event) {
              event.preventDefault(false);
          });   don't post yet

Comment: To hindmost: Could you write a full code for me? Thanks!

Comment: @HelloCW That's a wrong mod. You haven't read my comment carefully. I wrote "call preventDefault **depending** on...". This mean that `mySubmit`'s returning value should have effect on whether to call `preventDefault` or not.

Comment: Thanks! I call preventDefault(false) in order to test post, but it fail

Comment: I know I should to use preventDefault(mySubmit()) , but in order to test post I call preventDefault(false), and it fail

Comment: Could you write a full code for me?

Comment: @HelloCW no one here writes code for others. We help others work through an issue or something that are not seeing. I do not see where the data is `POST`'d to your upload script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on the example you made reference to and what I said in the comments, I do have a better example for you to consider.

**HTML**

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="File Upload">
  <p class="validateTips">Select a file to upload.</p>
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <label for="name">File</label>
      <input type="file" id="uploadFile" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      <!-- Allow form submission with keyboard without duplicating the dialog button -->
      <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>

<div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">
  <h1>Uploaded Files:</h1>
  <table id="users" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
    <thead>
      <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
        <th>File</th>
        <th>Folder</th>
        <th>Date</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Archive.xls</td>
        <td>/upload</td>
        <td>02/28/2017</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<button id="upload-file-button">Upload New File</button>
```

**CSS**

```
label,
input {
  display: block;
}

input.text {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  width: 95%;
  padding: .4em;
}

fieldset {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin: .6em 0;
}

div#users-contain {
  width: 350px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

div#users-contain table {
  margin: 1em 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

div#users-contain table td,
div#users-contain table th {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: .6em 10px;
  text-align: left;
}

.ui-dialog .ui-state-error {
  padding: .3em;
}

.validateTips {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 0.3em;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  var dialog, form;

  function updateTips(t) {
    $(".validateTips")
      .text(t)
      .addClass("ui-state-highlight");
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".validateTips").removeClass("ui-state-highlight", 1500);
    }, 500);
  }

  function uploadFile() {
    var valid = false;
    var $input = $("#uploadFile");
    if ($input[0].files.length === 0) {
      updateTips("You must select a file.");
      return valid;
    }
    var fileData = new FormData();
    $.each($input[0].files, function(k, v) {
      fileData.append(k, v);
    });
    // Barrowed from https://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax
    $.ajax({
      url: "./php/upload.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: fileData,
      cache: false,
      dataType: "JSON",
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: function(results, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        // 'results' will be a JSON object return from our form handler
        // 'results.error' may contain error details, like: Path Not Found
        if (typeof results.error === 'undefined') {
          // At this point, we should have uploaded the file
          // our form handler has return some response
          // We can update a table to do something with the data
          valid = true;
        } else {
          // Handle errors here
          updateTips("Error: " + results.error);
        }
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // Handle errors here
        updateTips("Error: " + textStatus);
        // STOP LOADING SPINNER
      }
    });
    return valid;
  }

  dialog = $("#dialog-form").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 400,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      "Upload": uploadFile,
      Cancel: function() {
        dialog.dialog("close");
      }
    },
    close: function() {
      form[0].reset();
    }
  });

  form = dialog.find("form").on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    uploadFile();
  });

  $("#upload-file-button").button().on("click", function() {
    dialog.dialog("open");
  });
});
```

As you can see, this is very similar to the original example in the way it works. It's not there through, since you have more work that has to be done server side.

Remember that jQuery is a framework for JavaScript, which is Client Side Scripting. To handle file uploads, your web server must be able to handle the HTTP POST data in some manner. This may be a CGI, ASP, ASP.NET, or PHP script.

I made a comment about https://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax which is a very straight forward article about using AJAX to upload a file to a PHP Script. I advise you read through it and continue your research so that you can better understand this action. Since now that you're letting users upload content, you are making your web site and possible your whole server open to attack via a backdoor script.

This will set you on the right path but the journey does not end here.